# .Net Maui - Create ImageSource from pixel data

Tags: c#, xaml, drawing, .net-maui

I have an twodimensional array which holds data for each pixel of an image. What I'm trying to do is to visualize this data in an .Net Maui (XAML).

My approach would be `<Image/>` where i bind the `ImageSource` property to my data and to write a custom `IValueConverter`. But that's where I'm struggling. I can't find a way to write a custom image source which works for all platforms.

Another idea was to use a `<Canvas/>` and draw the data manually. But this has some quirks. On smaller image scales (10x10) the result gets pretty blurry and i can't find any way to disable the antialising. To prevent that i would have to draw larger rectangles per pixel. But this would add some unnecessary complexity where i have to calculate the actual width and height and use that to calculate the rectangle sizes.

So what is the simplest and best way to display pixel data in an MAUI App?
To keep it simple we can say that we have a `byte[,]` (Greyscale) or a `Color[,]` array as data (whatever is simpler for the solution).

Comment: I've had to deal with something similar recently. My approach was also to use an IValueConverter to provide an ImageSource created from a byte array. I couldn't find a working implementation, though. I tried to use a Stream, but it didn't work.

Comment: SkiaSharp would give you better control for displaying an image built up pixel by pixel. I haven't used in Maui, but I assume it is similar to [SkiaSharp Graphics in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/).

Comment: Yes, SkiaSharp exists for MAUI and works just like it does for Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var byteArray = getImageByteArray(value as string);

        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what i was looking for. How is getImageByteArray(string) implemented?

Comment: Where is getImageByteArray implemented ?
How the heck do you convert a value from object to string without ever never mention what value is supposed to be but a string is not a byte array